# Swift Playgrounds aren't acting correctly after Xcode Update

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8, swift-playground

I have been making a Swift playground that uses the `touchesBegan` method to accept user interaction. It has been working fine, along with the NewtonsCradle and other Swift playgrounds I have downloaded from the internet. But I just updated my Xcode to version **8.3** and ***NO*** Swift playgrounds are currently working.

My Swift playground is no longer accepting any user input.
For example I set up a test view and when I click on it "touched" does not print:

```
class TestView : UIView {
public init() {

    super.init(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))


}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touched")
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

}
override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

}

}
var controller = TestView()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = controller
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

I also tried running the NewtonsCradle code (one updated for Swift 3.0 so that is not the problem) and the balls do **NOT** respond to user interaction and they just swing on their own. See this picture of them stuck in the up-left position: [image: NewtonsCradle]

Any one have any idea what is going wrong, or what I can do? I am really pressed for time to get this to work. I also cannot roll back to the previous version of Xcode as I need the Playground to work on the latest version.

EDIT: I just updated to MacOS 10.12.4 and it is ***still*** broken. Any help?

EDIT 2: I have gotten others to confirm this as an issue for them. Perhaps others can also confirm this and if possible file an Apple Bug Report as well or come up with a fix.

Comment: I am currently having the same problem and I have been working on it for the past few days. I think that you need to make sure the class you are accepting input from is a subclass of `UIViewController`. I am pretty sure the view controller is what allows actions to continue on after first run.

Comment: As far as I know, Apple is working on the issue. In the meantime, I suggest that you downgrade to the older version of Xcode and use that until it is fixed. You can get that here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=Xcode

Comment: @matt Obviously things like that are working, but it seems nothing to do with user interaction is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/74999) is quick fix from Apple Engineers

You just need to quit Xcode and execute following command in terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.xcode IDEPlaygroundDisableSimulatorAlternateFramebuffer -bool YES
```

It helped in my case where all `UIPanGestureRecognizers` stopped working after updating to Xcode 8.3.

Also note that this will decrease quality of rendered playground.

Comment: This, as it turns out, broke the sizing of my view. Oh well, guess we're waiting for it to be fixed by apple yet again

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of solutions:

- Clean Xcode (Shift+Command+K)
- Deep Clean Xcode (Shift+Option+Command+K)
- Insanely Clean Xcode (delete `/Library/Developer/DevrivedData`)

If that still doesn't work, **reinstall** Xcode:

Run:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools
sudo rm -rf /Developer
```

Then delete `Xcode.app` from the `applications` folder.

Comment: How should I go about cleaning it? The clean Xcode is grayed out? Also can you confirm that any Swift playground is working for you in Xcode 8.3? Could you run something like my sample code and try clicking it?

Comment: @brettf It is working for me, I have tried using playgrounds one day ago, but I haven't tried NewtonsCradle yet, try reinstalling Xcode then.